# Declaring a Sub/Function in another module accessible by other modules but not by user

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module `ModuleA` containing a `Public` function that the user will use on the spreadsheet:

```
Public Function UserCanSeeThis() As String
    UserCanSeeThis = "Hello, " & UserCannotSeeThisButModuleACan() & " user"
End Function
```

I have a module `ModuleB` which contains a function that I want to use in `ModuleA`, but I don't want the user to see in the list of available functions when writing `=` into a cell or when reading the formulae dictionary:

```
Function UserCannotSeeThisButModuleACan() As String
    UserCannotSeeThisButModuleACan = "my dear"
End Function
```

How should I declare the function in `ModuleB` so that `ModuleA` can see it, but the user cannot?

**p.s.** I've searched the site and only found the "solution" for `Sub`, I can declare the `Sub` as `Private` and then call it from the other module with `Application.Run "mySub"`. 
But I was hoping there was some more developed concept of "friendship" in VBA though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify `Option Private Module` at the top of `ModuleB`; public members won't be (visibly) exposed to the user, but will be readily available from anywhere inside the VBA project.

Your `Private`+`Application.Run` hack is.. well, a hack. Don't do that - make/leave public members `Public`, and hide the module from the macros list with `Option Private Module`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I was already using "Option Private Module", but still not declaring the function as Public (so the other module wasn't seeing it and I thought it wasn't the solution).

Comment: it also works if you make an optional argument to the macro. Wont appear in the macro list, but can launch it throuh vba, immediate window

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier sure, except I'd tend to remove a bogus unused parameter that's there just to do `Option Private Module`'s job... as would probably be "future self" OP, or anyone inheriting that code ;-)